# mod_substitute, new-line, tabs and other characters

Tags: regex, apache, substitution

I'm having problems using mod_substitute to write specific characters, specifically new-line, tabs and |-characters. The manual pages for Apache doesn't help me much here unfortunately.

I've put together this piece of code:

```
<IfModule mod_substitute.c>
  AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE text/html
  Substitute "s|<head>|<head><script src=\"tracker.js\"></script>|ni"
</IfModule>
```

This works as it should, however I'd like to add a new line and a tab between `<head>` and `<script>` but using standard regex of `\n\t` doesn't do the trick, it just prints out `\n\t` in the code.

I've also tried to print out the entire JavaScript code into the substitution, but it contains |-characters which I can't escape out.

Is there a way to accomplish this (formatting, or escaping |-characters) using substitutions? Is there an even better way to include code that I didn't think of perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

I have not figured out the newline part, but this worked for me to deal with the slashes, quotes, and pipes (I had to convert all single quotes to double in the script code Google provides.)

```
Substitute 's#<head>#<head><script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-XXXXXXXXXX"></script><script>window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);} gtag("js", new Date());gtag("config", "G-XXXXXXXXXX");</script>#ni'
```